# Appending raw header values to file for each request?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm attempting to dump raw headers for analytics into a TXT file, appending each request to a single file. The issue I'm running into is dealing with concurrent attempts to write to the same file across threads.

I'm not sure of the best approach. I'm currently using a HttpModule have tried using HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem as well as tried locking the file write.

How can I write every request's headers to a single file without running into threading issues? Thanks.

Comment: Rather than continuing to fight the threading issue with a file, have you considered using a database?

Comment: I will if I have to but I'm trying to make it easily accessible for those who are trying to access it. A SQL table would make things a little more tricky for them.

Comment: I didn't say SQL. I said a database. There's also non-relational databases such as [LiteDB](http://www.litedb.org/). Just put a web interface in front of it that exposes the data users need.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Log4Net and using a rolling file appender. I planned on eventually using this package anyway so it was a fit. Thanks to those who commented.